# Intersection of a ray and a delaunay triangulation

Tags: intersection, cgal, raytracing

How can I intersect a 3d ray with a 2D Constrained Delaunay Triangulation created from 3d points using the project_xy traits?

In a [cgal-discuss post](http://cgal-discuss.949826.n4.nabble.com/Intersection-segment-and-cells-from-3D-Delaunay-triangulation-td4660891.html) they comment using a tree if I have to make many queries. I don't have that many, thought, around 200 of them. I might have, however, lots of points, > 200 milion.

They also comment another approach:

> A third alternative is to locate an endpoint in the triangulation and
>   to walk towards the other end point collecting the cells you traverse.

But I don't understand how can we test that we've traversed the triangulation. In my case, the 3d triangulated mesh is a model of terrain, which is close to be a plane, meaning that most of the times only one intersection will exist and that I can bound the ray as a segment, if necessary.

Is it worth it to build a tree? what other approach could I follow? Iterating over all the faces seems highly inefficient.

Some typedefs I have, to give some context:

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Projection_traits_xy_3<K>  Gt;
typedef K::Point_3   Point3;

typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_2<Gt> Vb;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_mesh_face_base_2<Gt> Fb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb, Fb> Tds;
typedef CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2<Gt, Tds> CDT;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`line_walk()`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/classCGAL_1_1Triangulation__2.html#a19a4f322018b6bd16007f4cadbb381de)function to get all the cells in two traversed by the ray. Then you simply need to filter out them in 3D, using the segment-Triangle `do_intersect()` function.